# Verb to describe "being ignorant"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The answer to this is probably painfully obvious, but is there a verb to describe "being ignorant"?

I was discussing a sensitive subject with an LGBT friend and we touched on the ignorance of a certain individual. I was about to use a modified "haters gonna hate", but "ignorants gonna ignorant" is awful.

I wasn't going for grammatical excellence, the intention was to be silly, but it occurred to me that I've never learned a word to describe the **act** of being ignorant. Or perhaps I have and never made the connection.

Is there one?

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question. I'm looking to maintain the negative connotation of the word.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm looking to maintain the negative connotation of the word.

Comment: isn't it just **ignore**... *ignorants gonna ignore* OR *ignorers gonna ignore*

Comment: Hence my mention of "painfully obvious". I hadn't even considered that ignore is the root of ignorant! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ignoramuses are going to ignore**

> ignoramus
>         noun ig·no·ra·mus \ˌig-nə-ˈrā-məs also -ˈra-\   : a person who does not know much : an ignorant or stupid person    [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignoramus)

---

> ignore
>   1.1 Fail to consider (something significant):
>   the rules ignore one important principle of cricket   [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ignore)

Comment: Haters gonna hate", but "ignoramuses gonna ignore", sounds pretty good to me, much better than my suggestions.

Comment: This is perfect. And @JCG's modification to fit the "haters gonna hate" syntax is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

While there probably is a slew of verbs that could encapsulate the same sentiment, these two stand out in my mind:

[Dumb down](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dumb%20down) - to lower the level of difficulty and the intellectual content of

[Suppress](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suppress) - 
5
a :  to restrain from a usual course or action 
b :  to inhibit the growth or development of

Answer (score -1):

When I look at the word **ignorance** I think of a person who is actively ignoring as I use it in a sentence such as:

> If anyone persist in his deliberant ignorance ...

I cannot think of another way to express it in written form.